# Test A mock is being taken to Test B

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, patch

I have the following unit test in Python (using Python 3.8):

```
def test_Wrapper_permanent_cookie_OK_True(self):
    # Some stuff

    mock_3 = PermanentCookie
    mock_3.create_permanent_cookies_response = mock.Mock(return_value=response)

    # The following line uses this mock on its execution
    result = permanentcookies.Wrapper_permanent_cookie(Input)
    
    # Test passes (response gets defined previously)
    self.assertTrue(result == (response, None))
```

The issue starts when the following test is executed. It is the test to the function I mocked previously.

```
def test_create_permanent_cookies_response(self):

     permanentcookies = PermanentCookie()
     result = permanentcookies.create_permanent_cookies_response(status2, error2)

     # Test does not pass because "result" is not the execution of the function but the mock from the previous test (response gets defined previously)
     self.assertTrue(result == response)
```

Any suggestions on how to completely remove the previous mock/isolate each test from the rest/...?

Thanks in advance!

-------------------------------------------------------**EDIT**-------------------------------------

My test function is using patch method. But in these patches, there is a class that I need to test the function. Maybe I'm missing something basic on patching classes... My code:

```
    @mock.patch('src.servicios.permanent_cookies.PermanentCookie')
    @mock.patch('src.servicios.permanent_cookies.utilities.get_current_datetime')
    @mock.patch('src.servicios.permanent_cookies.queries.query_permanent_cookie')
    def test_Wrapper_permanent_cookie_OK_True(self, mock_1, mock_2, mock_3):

         # The following line is not sending my return_value expectation to function usage
         mock_3.create_permanent_cookies_response.return_value = 'test'


        # This is the usage of the class I mocked on the patch above
        permanentcookies = PermanentCookie()
        # Unexpected outcome as the method I passed the return_value method did not return that value.
        result = permanentcookies.Wrapper_permanent_cookie(Input)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the way to patch the function inside a class was first giving the class and then the function on the patch decorator. As long as the patch was on the decorator (and not inside the test as mock.Mock(return_value=...) ), the patch was properly done on the class' function level and not extended further than this test.

For all those arriving at this point as well, from the Edit, the answer was:

```
@mock.patch('src.servicios.permanent_cookies.PermanentCookie.create_permanent_cookies_response')
@mock.patch('src.servicios.permanent_cookies.utilities.get_current_datetime')
@mock.patch('src.servicios.permanent_cookies.queries.query_permanent_cookie')
def test_Wrapper_permanent_cookie_OK_True(self, mock_1, mock_2, mock_3):

    mock_3.return_value = 'Your Value'

    permanentcookies = PermanentCookie()
    # Now getting the correct 
    result = permanentcookies.Wrapper_permanent_cookie(Input)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually using [`patch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch) anywhere. It's using patch which *removes* the mock at the end of the test.

> `patch()` acts as a function decorator, class decorator or a context manager. Inside the body of the function or with statement, the *target* is patched with a *new* object. **When the function/with statement exits the patch is undone.**

Comment: How would you use patch then? Inline code would be much appreciated

Comment: The linked documentation shows how to use it, with code samples. Did you try yourself yet? Any issues?

Comment: Yes, I added the Edit section on the question. The problem is this patch does not behave as I expect...

Comment: Thanks a lot, @win! It seems the problem was as you described. Just modified a bit that line and it worked. Thanks a lot again! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ordinarily, a patch should not extend outside of its current context.

So everything patched in test 1:

```
@patch(...func1)
def test_test1(sef):
    func1() # <- patched.
```

Will be reset when you come to test 2:

```
def test_test2(sef):
    func1() # <- not patched.
```

But sometimes, you do need to keep an unpatched version of your function alongside a patched version:

in this case, you can do:

```
_unpatched = func1

@patch(...func1)
def test_patched_with_unpatched(self):
    func1()      # <- patched.
    _unpatched() # <- func1 not patched.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Florian Fasmeyer! It seems the problem was as you described. Just modified a bit that line and it worked. Thanks a lot again! :)